Adding a data-dependent term to the porous medium equation while retaining an explicit solution
I am working with the porous medium equation, which I am treating it as a type of Fokker-Planck equation given by:
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \Delta(u^m), \quad m > 1
$
For this equation, the Barenblatt solution provides a closed-form probability density:
$
u(x, t) = C t^{-\alpha d} \left( 1 - \frac{\|x\|^\beta}{c^\beta t^{\beta \alpha}} \right)_+^\gamma
$
where C is the normalisation constant and the support is $\|x\| \leq c t^\alpha$ and all other parameters are scalars and $(x)_+ := \max(x, 0)$.
While the Barenblatt solution is explicit, it is not data-dependent, meaning that its parameters are scalar and cannot be estimated or tuned based on a dataset. I am interested in incorporating a data-dependent term into the porous medium equation to retain an explicit solution that can be adapted based on data, like estimating mean and covariance of a Gaussian distribution from the data.
My idea is to add a drift term to the Fokker-Planck equation (essentially adding a linear drift term to the porous medium equation), which would make the overall equation:
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{b}(x, t) u) + \Delta(u^m)$
where b is a data dependent term.
The goal is to choose b(x,t) such that:

The resulting Fokker-Planck equation still allows for an explicit solution.
The solution becomes data-dependent, enabling parameter estimation or tuning based on data.

Is my approach to adding a data-dependent drift term to the porous medium equation theoretically sound? Are there known methods or results that can guide this process? How can I have such a solution for the modified Fokker Planck equation?
